# NTextCat how it works

Tags: c#

if anyone know how i can use NTextCat in c#,  I've downloaded but I found many of dll files, i don't know what i should use. This is its website  http://ntextcat.codeplex.com
i found i code:

```
var factory = new RankedLanguageIdentifierFactory();
 var identifier = factory.Load("Core14.profile.xml");
 var languages = identifier.Identify("your text to get its language identified");
 var mostCertainLanguage = languages.FirstOrDefault();
 if (mostCertainLanguage != null)  
    Console.WriteLine("The language of the text is '{0}' (ISO639-3  code)",mostCertainLanguage.Item1.Iso639_3);  
 else 
    Console.WriteLine("The language couldn’t be identified with an acceptable degree of certainty");
```

but what i should do first what a dll i should use ect..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did it by the way, for who's interested:

1. copy the folder you downloaded to your directory
2. browse and import dll `IvanAkcheurov.NTextCat.Lib.dll` and add it to the references of the project
3. In your code:

   ```
   using IvanAkcheurov.NTextCat.Lib;

   // ....
   // <YOUR CODE>
   // ....
   var factory = new RankedLanguageIdentifierFactory();
   var identifier = factory.Load("NTextCat 0.2.1.1\\LanguageModels\\Core14.profile.xml");
   var languages = identifier.Identify("your text to get its language identified");
   var mostCertainLanguage = languages.FirstOrDefault();
   if (mostCertainLanguage != null)  
       Console.WriteLine("The language of the text is '{0}' (ISO639-3  code)",mostCertainLanguage.Item1.Iso639_3);  
   else 
       Console.WriteLine("The language couldn’t be identified with an acceptable degree of certainty");
   ```

In the line `var identifier = factory.Load....` you must pay attention to language profile you'll need to use. For example, I use `Wiki82.profile.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Manage Nuget Packages" in Visual Studio and Search for NTextCat... the nuget package will pop up (make sure it's the one by Ivan). Click install and it will install all DLLs needed.